# iCloud requests fail with timeout after a few minutes of connectivity

Tags: mac, icloud, wifi, calendar

When connecting to a wifi network and waiting for a short period of time (ranging from 20 seconds to 5 minutes), certain iCloud related requests will result in a timeout.

I found the error first in BusyCal, a third party calendar app, when trying to sync iCloud calendars, but it also occurs in the native calendar app. Both apps try syncing for about 20 seconds and give an error sign afterwards. The error even manages to beachball system preference panes for iCloud and internet accounts (sometimes).

I inspected console and found that there are requests failing with a timeout (in German: "Zeitüberschreitung"). Here is a log item for the process `com.apple.iCloudHelper`:

```
AOSKit ERROR: Storage usage request failed, appleID=MY_APPLE_ID, url=https://p29-quota.icloud.com:443/quotaservice/external/osx/1060093596/storageUsageInfo, requestHeaders=
{
    "Accept-Language" = "de-de";
    Authorization = "...";
    "X-Mme-Client-Info" = "<MacBookPro12,1> <Mac OS X;10.12.6;16G1114> <com.apple.AOSKit/252 (com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/2.0)>";
    "X-Mme-Country" = DE;
    "X-Mme-Device-Id" = "191F7B8A-ED81-5E19-85BD-5690FA246D47";
    "X-Mme-Timezone" = MEZ;
},
error=Error Domain=AOSErrorDomain Code=1000 "(null)" UserInfo={UnderlyingError=Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://p29-quota.icloud.com:443/quotaservice/external/osx/1060093596/storageUsageInfo, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://p29-quota.icloud.com:443/quotaservice/external/osx/1060093596/storageUsageInfo, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforde
```

Here is another log item for process `CalendarAgent`:

```
[com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.mismatch] [Sync report for calendar home iCloud, failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa1138a5c40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://MY_APPLE_ID@p29-caldav.icloud.com/1060093596/calendars/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://MY_APPLE_ID@p29-caldav.icloud.com/1060093596/calendars/, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://MY_APPLE_ID@p29-caldav.icloud.com/1060093596/calendars/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://MY_APPLE_ID@p29-caldav.icloud.com/1060093596/calendars/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=Zeitüberschreitung bei der Anforderung.}]
```

(If there's anything too confidential in there, please let me know.)

The error occurs on 2 different wifi networks. Once I disable and reenable wifi, everything works for a short period of time until the error occurs again. Error is wifi only and doesn't occur when tethered to an iPhone's 3G connection.

Things I tried so far without success:

- deleting `/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist`,
- rebooting in safe mode and
- wondering what I might have done to deserve this

I'm on a MacBook Pro with Sierra (10.12.6). Happy to provide more info if needed.

Any ideas? I'm pretty desperate over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, my provider screwed something up. Couldn't get more detail than "some iCloud IPs were blacklisted" from the person I talked to. But everything's working again and that makes me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an DNS problem. 
Could you check if the resolution of host p29-quota.icloud.com works with your DNS server?

```
admin:~$ host p29-quota.icloud.com
p29-quota.icloud.com is an alias for p29-quota.fe.apple-dns.net.
p29-quota.fe.apple-dns.net has address 17.248.147.21
p29-quota.fe.apple-dns.net has address 17.248.147.19
```

If not try a differnet DNS server like google: 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turned out to be an error on my provider's side 

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What ist the name of your provider?

Comment: "an!", which is a subsidiary of "HL komm" in Germany.